# continue for loop inside internal function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to do the following:

```
for line in lines:
   handle(line)
   if cond:
      handle_lines_cond() # will handle multiple lines. for loop will continue where handle_cond() left off
```

I need to do this with a decent performance, if possible

Comment: there isn't much clarity ,please prove more details ,as far I have understood you can use a counter count the line no and pass this counter value to your 'handle line count' function

Answer (score 0):

To do this it will be better to use while:

```
i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    handle(lines[i])
    if cond:
      i = handle_lines_cond()  # where handle_lines_cond returns the last line index which was processed
    else:
      i = i + 1
```

Comment: simple enough to have thought about it myself. Solved

Comment: simple enough to have thought about it myself. Solved